# angular - while remove decimal point value in form control with the type number, cursor moves to first position

Tags: angular

**code structure:**

```
<div class="portalView">
  <div class="headerRow">
    ....
    <input type="number" formControlName="age" value="getAgeValue()">
    ....
  </div>
  <div>
    ....
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mobileView">
  <div class="headerRow">
    ....
    ....
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="number" formControlName="age" value="getAgeValue()">
    ....
  </div>
</div>
```

here I have to maintain a same formControl in two places in order to achieve different view based on device length.

**problem:**

1)If I don't use getAgeValue() then the value update of a one formControl not reflecting in another.

2)if I use getAgeValue(), facing this below issue
-> when edit decimal point value, ex: "45.67" to "45.", the cursor moves to first position (before "4")

-> it's happening because, the value change takes place from getAgeValue()

-> local formControl having value "45." and the getAgeValue() returning "45", so the cursor movement happening.

Above are the problems, I am stuck in here for last 2 days, searched in several resources but didn't get any suitable solution.

If anyone knows or any better suggestions, please let me know. any reference like handling it into a single code (instead of separate code for mobile and portal) or any solution to handle this cursor movement.

Comment: used ngIf to show and hide portal/mobile view. which reloads the form each time the view changed and worked in expected way. note: previously used css to handle this